# how to initial a view controller that with tab bar inside?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I do not know how to initialize a view controller that included a tab bar and there are 2 view controller in the tab bar?

I have a current_view_controller, a OrderPanel, a firstViewController, and a SecondViewController.

The firstViewController and SecondViewController are the tabs inside OrderPanel. How do i correctly initialize and call the OrderPanel in current_view_controller?

This is the class OrderPanel that set up the tabs into a view controller

```
  #import "OrderPanel.h"

  #import "OrderPanelFirstViewController.h"

  #import "OrderPanelSecondViewController.h"

  @implementation OrderPanel

  @synthesize window = _window;
  @synthesize tabBarController = _tabBarController;

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:            (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    viewController1 = [[OrderPanelFirstViewController alloc]       initWithNibName:@"OrderPanelFirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[OrderPanelSecondViewController alloc]       initWithNibName:@"OrderPanelSecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else {
    viewController1 = [[OrderPanelFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrderPanelFirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    viewController2 = [[OrderPanelSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OrderPanelSecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
}
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

so how do i call the orderPanel in my current view controller?

```
 - (IBAction)T1pressed:(id)sender {
         // how do i call order panel?

}
```

Comment: you're assuming something and posting something.Half of the details you ate while explaining.Please edit the above question and brief what exactly you want...

Comment: I want a tab view on top of a tab view.

Comment: like    tab controller with 2 tabs  <- this is easy to do because the Xcode IDE helped me, but if i want to add a tab controller with 2 tabs again inside one of those old tab. how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[firstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1 ,viewController2, nil];

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: what is the viewControllers?

Comment: @user1933421 An array of the root view controllers displayed by the tab bar interface.

Comment: i think i should not use tabbarcontroll to represent the class

Comment: i used the name called OrderPanel to make a tab bar and added those 2 view inside, but i dun know how to call the orderPanel in the currentviewcontroll

Comment: I never call a view controller in objective-c before. please guide me

Comment: @user1933421 if you initialized at app delegate it will visible in your current view controller also

Comment: but i dun know how to initialized it. The term delegate is not familiar to me. i am not quite understand how delegate, root controller, and navigation stuff.

Comment: @user1933421 means your OrderPanel

Comment: u mean i am going to initialized the OrderPanel only? like just OrderPanel *view = [[OrderPanel alloc] init]; like this?  i did this before, but nothing show up.